# WM_COMMAND - How do I get an ID from another applications menuitem?

Tags: delphi

I need to do it programatically similar to Spy++.  All I need is the one WM_COMMAND message returned so I can retrieve the Command ID.  Does anyone have source on this?  I really appreciate it...

I am currently using Delphi...

Answer (score 2):

Not a trivial job; you need global hooks. Read about how Spy++ does it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/01/16/spy-internals.aspx). See a Delphi implementation example [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1212).